# Paclet server down?

Tags: bugs, wolfram-cloud, web-access, paclets

out and unable to connect to the paclet server and Mathematica asking me to log in. Is very annoying and gets worse. Do other users also have this problem?

[image]

Comment: Working OK for me (Mathematica 11.2 under macOS 10.12.6).

Comment: There is a proxy-related bug in 11.2 that would cause this. Try a direct connection, or if that is not an option, please get in touch with support who can provide an updated CURLLink paclet.

Comment: @ilian thanks for the tip. I filled a support call.

Comment: Issue fixed with update thanks @ilian

Answer (score 7):

Transferring my comment into an answer,

> There is a proxy-related bug in 11.2 that would cause this behavior. Try a
>   direct connection, or if that is not an option, please get in touch
>   with support who can provide an updated `CURLLink` paclet.

Comment: I there any reference to your bug report ?

Comment: If you are talking to support, you can just point them to this question (157512) on MSE.